# ASP.NET MSSQL fails to connect via web app, but succeeds in Server Explorer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Tech used:

- Visual Studio 2015
- ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 RC1
- Identity via EF 7

I've successfully made a connection to a remote MSSQL server using the Server Explorer UI within VS2015.  When I say "remote", I mean not on the same machine as my dev machine, but a machine that is local to the network.

Here is the connection string, which is the same in the Server Explorer (works) and the appsettings.json (doesn't work):

> "Data Source=DBSERVER\INSTANCE1;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=ASPNET-Db-User;Password=thepassword"

I'm using SQL Authentication in both cases.

When I copy the connection string from the server explorer and plug it into appsettings.json and try to connect to the db in order to create an Identity user account via the "register account" view, I get a connection error:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

It seems that, clearly, the SQL instance is reachable, but somehow ASP.NET isn't able to connect to it.

Any idea how I might trouble shoot this?

Comment: whats the connection string you're using?

Comment: What type of authentication did you use when connecting to the database from server explorer? Is it SQL Authentication or Windows Authentication

Comment: I'm using SQL Authentication in both cases.  I've updated the question with the connection string.  Thank you.

Comment: can u check sql server configuration manager (server where sql is installed) > SQL native client configuration > client protocols?  make sure TCP/IP and named pipes are enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I checked all protocols and everything is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code in MVC5 and everything works as expected.  I believe this to be a MVC 6 error and have opened a bug report at

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4586

Answer (score 0):

After chatting with the folks building MVC 6, it turns out that the CoreCLR does not support named pipes.  Using a fully qualified address and an explicit port sorts the problem.